# Has Abort Evaluation changed in M12.1

Tags: abort

I've noticed that in M12 abort evaluation doesn't behave the same as it has done in previous versions. for example if I have some form of batch fitting routine:

```
    Monitor[       
    Table[
                   Data = Import[MyListOfData[[i]]];
                   MyFit = NonlinearModelFit[Data, FitModel, {a, b, c}, x];

                      DataWithFitPlot = Show[{Plot[MyFit[x],{x, xMin, XMax}], ListPlot[Data]}];
                   {i, MyFit},
                   {i, 1, Length[MyListOfData]}
                ];,
    DataWithFitPlot
]
```

I can no longer abort the evaluation and have to quit the Kernel entirely. Is this a known bug? In M12 and M11 I had no problems.

---

In an attempt to make this question a bit more useful, here is some very basic code that replicates the problem:

```
    Monitor[    
               Table[
               Data = Table[{x, Sin[1 x] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
               FittedData = NonlinearModelFit[Data, Sin[\[Omega] x], {{\[Omega], 1}}, x];
                        FittedDataPlot = 
        Show[{Plot[FittedData[x], {x, 0 , 10}], ListPlot[Data]}];,
                    {i, 1, 20}
                ];,
            FittedDataPlot
        ]
```

I cannot abort this evaluation, and I have to quit the kernel. In M12, and M11 I didn't have to do this.

If I remove `Monitor` the problem persists, if I remove `Plot` the problem persists.

Comment: (1) I assume you mean using the Front End's Evalution > Abort Evaluation and not a plain terminal window kernel interface with <ctrl-c>. It would be useful to know whether it is the `Import` or `NonlinearModelFit` that is not abortable. Thiis can probably be determined using `Print` statements. Also it is possible that `Monitor` is involved so I will suggest removing that to see if things change.

Comment: (2) This is really a matter for Tech Support. It might turn out to be a bug and we will need input to duplicate it. Which might not be easily provided in MSE (though if you can do so, that would be useful).

Comment: (3) I suppose `Plot` could also be a culprit, although i think that is the least likely among the plausible suspects.

Comment: All of your suggestions make sense, however it conflicts with my experience in previous versions. I completely understand the code "sample" I have provided isn't ideal. I will try and put together an example that is easily replicated and produces the same outcome.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I added some sample code that replicates the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look (probably not before tomorrow though).

Comment: I wonder if this is platform/OS dependent? I ran it in 12.1 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04. It aborted just fine using the menu Evaluation > Abort Evaluation. I set the loop range to 100 instead of 20 so I'd have ample time to get to that menu. I also set the `x` increment to .0001 so as to encourage the abort to happen while in NonlinearModelFit innards. My guess is that in your case the `Abort` happens while in some MKL library code used by the fit function, and that library code is not reacting well to a signal; this could be platform dependent behavior. But it is just speculation on my part.

Comment: Addendum: I think at this point you should contact Tech Support and provide platform details. Also check whether this variant is abortable: `data = Table[{x, 
    Sin[x] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]]}, {x, 0, 10, 
    0.0001}];
Do[NonlinearModelFit[data, Sin[\[Omega] x], {{\[Omega], 1}}, x];, 
  300];` It removes several layers that might be extransous. If it aborts cleanly, try to pare down your issue to a MWE ( "minimal working example: a misnomer since it is really a minimal failing example, but you get the idea).

Comment: That's interesting. I'm on 12.1 on Windows 10. I think I'll raise it with tech support.